# How to handle a composite primary key in adminbro/adminjs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, admin-bro, adminjs

- I have 3 tables

**accounts**

| id | email | email_verified | is_primary | password | picture_url | social_account_id | username | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**users**

| id | enabled | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

**user_accounts**

| account_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

As you notice my user_accounts table has a composite primary key (account_id, user_id) How do I manage this on adminbro/adminjs?

I think it currenty takes one of them as the primary key automatically

[image]

My main complaint is that I am unable to create any records for this table currently

[image]

**My adminbro route**

```
import { sequelize } from '../../data/models';

import AdminBro from 'adminjs';
import AdminBroExpress from '@adminjs/express';
import AdminBroSequelize from '@adminjs/sequelize';

AdminBro.registerAdapter(AdminBroSequelize);
const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  rootPath: '/admin',
  resources: [
    {
      resource: sequelize.models.Account,
      options: {
        parent: {
          name: 'Database',
          icon: 'Api',
        },
        listProperties: [
          'id',
          'email',
          'emailVerified',
          'isPrimary',
          'password',
          'pictureUrl',
          'socialAccountId',
          'username',
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resource: sequelize.models.User,
      options: {
        parent: {
          name: 'Database',
          icon: 'Api',
        },
        listProperties: ['id', 'enabled'],
      },
    },
    {
      resource: sequelize.models.UserAccount,
      options: {
        parent: {
          name: 'Database',
          icon: 'Api',
        },
        listProperties: ['id', 'accountId', 'userId'],
      },
    },
  ],
  branding: {
    companyName: 'API',
    logo: false,
    favicon: 'https://imagine.ai/img/favicon.ico',
    withMadeWithLove: false,
  },
});
const adminbroRouter = AdminBroExpress.buildRouter(adminBro);

export default adminbroRouter;
```

**EDIT 1**

**UserAccount.model.ts**

```
/* eslint import/no-cycle: "off" */
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import {
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Column,
  Table,
  Default,
  IsUUID,
  ForeignKey,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Account, User } from 'data/models';

@Table({
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'user_accounts',
})
export default class UserAccount extends Model {
  @ForeignKey(() => Account)
  @PrimaryKey
  @IsUUID(4)
  @Default(DataTypes.UUIDV4)
  @Column
  accountId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @PrimaryKey
  @IsUUID(4)
  @Default(DataTypes.UUIDV4)
  @Column
  userId: string;
}
```

Comment: can you show your model definition for `UserAccount`?

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize can't work with composite PKs properly.

Comment: @Anatoly sequelize or adminjs? because sequelize tables are created perfectly in the database with composite keys

Comment: Yes, I meant Sequelize. Though you have composite PKs foreign keys don't support them. The official documentation almost silint about composite PKs and it's the clear sign for me. Even v7 alpha does not have any explicit mentions of composite keys (still mentions them only in M:N associations for junction tables themselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rafał Dzięgielewski:

> A single primary key is currently required, this is mostly because of
> how app routing works in AdminJS.

[AdminJS on Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Wfn.png)