# How do I make both these columns as a composite primary key?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, sequelize-typescript

I have a model in sequelize that stores like dislike votes. It needs to know which post was liked/disliked and by which user. I am using sequelize-typescript

**likeDislike.model.ts**

```
/* eslint import/no-cycle: "off" */
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import {
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Column,
  Table,
  Default,
  IsUUID,
  BelongsTo,
  Unique,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Account, FeedItem } from 'data/models';

@Table({
  createdAt: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'feed_item_like_dislike_votes',
  updatedAt: false,
})
export default class FeedItemLikeDislikeVote extends Model {
  @Column
  vote: boolean;

  @BelongsTo(() => Account, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'accountId', allowNull: false },
    as: 'account_',
  })
  @Column({ type: DataTypes.UUID, field: 'account_id' })
  account: Account;

  @BelongsTo(() => FeedItem, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'feedItemId', allowNull: false },
    as: 'feedItem_',
  })
  @Column({ type: DataTypes.UUID, field: 'feed_item_id' })
  feedItem: FeedItem;
}
```

How do I make a composite primary key (account, feedItem) such that it is also a foreign key to account and feedItem respectively?

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize dos not support composite FKs as I mentioned in the other question comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73986092/how-to-handle-a-composite-primary-key-in-adminbro-adminjs?noredirect=1#comment130665426_73986092

Comment: @Anatoly what about sequelize migrations? the models may not support a composite foreign key but what happens if you try putting one inside a migration file and then start using it

Comment: Well, models are used regardless what columns and table you have in DB after applying migrations. What you define in models is what you get (if the model was defined correctly).

Comment: @Anatoly but the actual query would use the DB created by the migration would it not? so if you have a pair of columns (user_id, account_id) which is not defined as a primary key in the model but as a primary key in the migration, the indexing still takes effect no?

Comment: Even if Sequelize will detect composite PK properly you can't indicate two fields in associations to link two tables by two fields.

Comment: @Anatoly so the only workaround is to have an id column with composite unique constraint i am guessing in both model and migration

Comment: If you want to guarantee that there will be no two records with the same account id and feed id then yes you need an unique index (not PK) on both fields.

Comment: @Anatoly thank you for the clarification, if the primary key was not composite would it work then? like having the same column as both primary key and foreign key in the model as well as migration

Comment: You need a separate surrogate PK field (id) and an unique index on a pair of `accountId` and `feedItemId`